# Welcome back, you've already connected with this app via Google+ Sign-In as *

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm working with Google App Engine using python and `OAuth2.0` (Google Accounts, not Google+) as log in medium into my application, and it has been fine for the last half year and working good, now there a message that gets displayed every time I run my application that looks like this:

[image: preview of errro]

Why does this keep on promoting every time I load my application? And second of all, why is it saying I connected this app with Google+ ( I don't even have one) when I did not, the decorator used is `OAuth2Decorator`. Hope someone can help.

**Edit2** I was asked for the code example and here the whole javascript auth2.0 flow.

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';

function checkAuth() { gapi.auth.init(load); }
function load() { gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', auth); }

function auth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize(
      {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
      handleAuthResult);
}

function handleClientLoad() {
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  //$('#intro').center().fadeIn('slow');
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
  } else {
    // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
  }
}
```

Comment: Some code would be nice..

Comment: @PeterVaro The thing is that i have not changed the code. It's the same. but will add.

Comment: I started getting the same popup when using JS GAPI recently. Also haven't changed anything all i do is `var authConfig = {client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true }

gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
gapi.auth.authorize(authConfig, handleAuthResult);`

Comment: @MarcinIgnac So I'm not the only one, if you find a solution please mention it here. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterVaro Code added to question.

Comment: This is due to the immediate: true, it causes the popup, I am talking with some googlers about this issue now.

Comment: Is there already a solution to this question? THX for the Information.

Comment: @winner_joiner No, not yet.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian I'm not sure where your pulling this false information from but there no Drive v3.

Comment: @Jessica this was caused by a bug that should be fixed now, is it still happening?

Comment: @Silvano Yes, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the code that made this message prompt up. Thank you who ever at Google fixed this.

Should be gone.